# Object detection to only assign unique ID

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolov5

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

class YOLO_Pred():
    def __init__(self, onnx_model, data_yaml):
        # load YAML
        with open(data_yaml, mode='r') as f:
            data_yaml = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)

        self.labels = data_yaml['names']
        self.nc = data_yaml['nc']
        self.class_counts = {}

        # load YOLO model
        self.yolo = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(onnx_model)
        self.yolo.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
        self.yolo.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)


    def get_next_object_id(self):
        self.object_id += 1
        return self.object_id

    def predictions(self, image):
        row, col, d = image.shape
        # get the YOLO prediction from the image
        # step-1 convert image into square image (array)
        max_rc = max(row, col)
        input_image = np.zeros((max_rc, max_rc, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        input_image[0:row, 0:col] = image
        # step-2: get prediction from square array
        INPUT_WH_YOLO = 640
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(input_image, 1/255, (INPUT_WH_YOLO, INPUT_WH_YOLO), swapRB=True, crop=False)
        self.yolo.setInput(blob)
        preds = self.yolo.forward()  # detection or prediction from YOLO

        # Non Maximum Supression
        # step-1: filter detection based on confidence (0.4) and probability score (0.25)
        detections = preds[0]
        boxes = []
        confidences = []
        classes = []

        # widht and height of the image (input_image)
        image_w, image_h = input_image.shape[:2]
        x_factor = image_w / INPUT_WH_YOLO
        y_factor = image_h / INPUT_WH_YOLO

        self.object_id = 0  # Reset object ID counter for each frame

        for i in range(len(detections)):
            row = detections[i]
            confidence = row[4]  # confidence of detecting an object
            if confidence > 0.4:
                class_score = row[5:].max()  # maximum probability from 20 objects
                class_id = row[5:].argmax()  # get the index position at which max probability occurs

                if class_score > 0.25:
                    cx, cy, w, h = row[0:4]
                    # construct bounding box from four values
                    # left, top, width, and height
                    left = int((cx - 0.5 * w) * x_factor)
                    top = int((cy - 0.5 * h) * y_factor)
                    width = int(w * x_factor)
                    height = int(h * y_factor)

                    box = np.array([left, top, width, height])

                    # append values into the list
                    confidences.append(confidence)
                    boxes.append(box)
                    classes.append(class_id)

        # clean
        boxes_np = np.array(boxes).tolist()
        confidences_np = np.array(confidences).tolist()

        # NMS
        # index = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes_np,confidences_np,0.25,0.45).flatten()
        index = np.array(cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes_np, confidences_np, 0.25, 0.45)).flatten()

        # Draw the Bounding
        for ind in index:
            # extract bounding box
            x, y, w, h = boxes_np[ind]
            bb_conf = int(confidences_np[ind] * 100)
            classes_id = classes[ind]
            class_name = self.labels[classes_id]
            color = (0, 0, 255)  # default color: Blue

            # Check if the class is helmet (0) or vest (2)
            if classes_id == 0 or classes_id == 2:
                color = (0, 255, 0)  # green color for helmet or vest

            else:
                color = (0, 0, 255)  # red color for other classes
                folder_name = "SAVED_DATA"
                if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
                    os.makedirs(folder_name)
                count = self.class_counts.get(class_name, 0) + 1
                self.class_counts[class_name] = count
                file_name = f"{folder_name}/{class_name}_{count}.jpg"

                while os.path.exists(file_name):
                    count += 1
                    file_name = f"{folder_name}/{class_name}_{count}.jpg"

                cv2.imwrite(file_name, image)

            object_id = self.get_next_object_id()  # Get the next object ID
            id_text = f'ID: {object_id}'  # Format the ID text

            # Draw ID text in yellow color to the left of the bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 5)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x - 120, y - 30), (x, y), color, -1)
            cv2.putText(image, id_text, (x - 100, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(image, f'{class_name}: {bb_conf}%', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 0, 34), 2)

        return image
```

In this code when object is detect it assign ID for eg(in camera there are object a,b,c,d then ID will be like a-1,b-2,c-3,d-4). Now the issue is when object get out of camera it reassign all ID for eg.(if 'a' move out of frame it will reassign all values b-1,c-2,d-3) rather than this I want that ID remain Fix and when any new object came in camera a new unique ID should be assign .

output needed:
a-1,b-2,c-3,d-4
when 'a' move out of camera then id's should be
b-2,c-3,d-4
and when new object came then
b-2,c-3,d-4,e-5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has something to do with this function:

```
def get_next_object_id(self):
    self.object_id += 1
    return self.object_id
```

that is called in this line:

```
object_id = self.get_next_object_id()  # Get the next object ID
        id_text = f'ID: {object_id}'  # Format the ID text
```

having it set to += 1 is going to continuously increase the ID number. I believe by just setting the id_text to the self.object_id variable it should fix it.

```
id_text = f'ID: {self.object_id}'
```